# Bind textbox to dictionary using a variable key

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, reactiveui

I want to implement a dynamic UI where TextBox controls will be created dynamically, and their content bound to a Dictionary on the ViewModel.

I'm trying to implement two-way data binding using ReactiveUI.

The issue I'm facing is that I only seem to be allowed to bind the TextBoxes to an entry in the Dictionary if I use a literal string as the key, but as soon as I try to use a string variable to setup the binding, I get the following error:

```
Index expressions are only supported with constants.
```

Here is a very simplified sample of what I'm trying to do. The TextBox is not dynamically instantiated in order to isolate the problem:

```
string PropNum = "22017";
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ExcelData[PropNum], view => view.tbCreate.Text);
```

In this example, `ExcelData` is a `Dictionary<string, object>` defined on the ViewModel.

On the other hand, the following works fine:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.ExcelData["22017"], view => view.tbCreate.Text);
```

I need the lookup key to be a variable. Any ways to achieve this result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do what you want with Bind()

We use Expression> to determine where the binding should come from. As the error message said you have to use constants if you want to use indexes.

To give you an idea what the Expression is doing, Expression allows you to use details about a lambda a user provides.

```
this.Bind(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.Property1.Property2.Property3)
```

With Expression's you get details about each property/object along the way.

What we do is subscribe to each object along the way's PropertyChanged event (if the object is not null), and we'll also set values appropriately to the other property.

Expression have a limitation of having to be constant since it's mostly a compile time feature.

In terms of what you want to achieve you'll have to do everything after your dynamic value. So you can subscribe to the PropertyChange events once you've resolved the ExcelData index.

You can potentially use WhenAnyValue() on the resolved object,

```
myViewModel.ExcelData[propertyIndex].WhenAnyValue(x => x.Value).BindTo(this.ViewModel, view => view.TextBox.Text);
this.WhenAnyValue(view => view.TextBox.Text).BindTo(myViewModel.ExcelData[propertyIndex], x => x.Value);
```

You need the two BindTo due to it being OneWayOnly, and I've used the assumption you have a Value property on your ExcelData object.

Be aware your ExcelData object contained at the propertyIndex must also be derived off *INotifyPropertyChanged*

Comment: I may be wrong, and the docs are not 100% clear about this, but isn't `BindTo` only one-way binding?

Comment: Yes that's correct but nothing stopping you from doing two statements. What Bind/WhenAnyValue do is they take in a Expression<T>, which they then read each property contained within and subscribe to property changes (We have a mechanism that allows us to detect the best binding mechanism). So your technique of using a non-constant value isn't going to work there. So you're effectively left with building that chain yourself and you can do that by doing WhenAnyValue chains. I've in the past have created extension methods to help with this type of scenario.

Comment: I had seen the overload taking an `Expression`, but I admit I'd need to see some example to wrap my head around how to use it. Can you edit your answer with some sample code?

Comment: The answer is the answer, what you want isn't possible with Bind(), you'd have to use some other mechanism to get property updates.

Comment: I agree, but I've been trying to get your suggestion of `ViewModel.ExcelData[Row].WhenAnyValue()` to work without success. Nothing gets "triggered". If you have done something similar in the past, could you please update your answer with some code?

Comment: Does the modified answer help?

Comment: I guess your last sentence nailed it down for me. As mentioned in my OP, `ExcelData` is of type `Dictionary<string, object>`, so no INPC. I have to rethink my approach if INPC is required.

Comment: What is funny though, is that `Bind`, using a literal key, picks up the changes in the object even if it doesn't implement INPC.

Comment: Yeah, the BindTo() will only pick up value changes and then bind. Bind() will also grab the initial value for POCO types. You can just achieve the same thing by setting the value onto your target control directly.

Comment: Glenn, what you say about picking up the initial value is very interesting. Do you know of resources that would help me learn about those "hidden" pearls of knowledge about RxUI? I don't mind buying books if needed.

Comment: Kent Boogart (one of my fellow RxUI maintainers) released a book earlier this year. Worth getting a copy and goes through a lot of these tricks https://kent-boogaart.com/you-i-and-reactiveui/